# PHP - Remove characters and separate numbers

Tags: php

Does anyone know PHP code that would strip any characters from string except number. But if there is space between numbers it would separate them.

Example input:

```
$input = '28  -  200 mm';
```

Output:

```
$num1 = 28;
$num2 = 200;
```

Thank you!

Comment: I only success striping characters and keep numbers. But don't know how to separate numbers.

Comment: what do you mean by separate numbers?

Comment: I've just updated my question. In input I get that value $input = '28  -  200 mm'; and I would like to remove all characters (mm) and split group of numbers separately.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
   $str = '28  -  200 mm';
   $pattern = '#(?P<numbers>\d+)#';
   if(preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches)){
       foreach ($matches['numbers'] as $number) {
           echo $number;
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your basic regex would look like:

```
#\b(\d+)\b#
        ^^ word boundary
    ^^^ one or more digits
```

So something like:

```
preg_match_all('#\b(\d+)\b#', $your_string, $results);
```

And the results would be stored in the `$results` array, see the manual on [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

Answer (score 0):

You would have a better chance using Regex with your problem.

But here is quick a solution :

```
$string = "28 - 100 mm";
$arr = explode(" ",$string);
$numbers = array();
foreach($arr as $value)
{
    if(intval($value))
        $numbers[] = intval($value);
}
```

Which results in `array(2) { [0]=> int(28) [1]=> int(100) }`

Comment: Ty. I just used $number[0] and $number[1] to get results outside loop.